# Static Initialize of Vector w/ Structure w/ char buffer[]

Tags: c++, char, buffer, structure

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//
// g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
//
// ERROR:
//
// vectorInit-StackFault.cpp:10:32: error: could not convert ‘{{"a", "d"}}’ from
// ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<N>’
// std::vector<N> VN1 = {{"a","d"}};
//
struct N {
    uint8_t b_1[2];
    uint8_t b_2[2];
};

std::vector<N> VN1 = {{"a","d"}};

int main(void) {
    for (auto n : VN1)
        std::cout << n.b_1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to statically initialize a vector with a structure that has a buffer[].

Code is included.

Want to be able to statically initialize, creating test code with google mock and gtest.

Comment: `"a"` is a `const char[2]`, not a `uint8_t[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that `uint8_t` is an alias of `unsigned char` (and that assumption should hold on that system), the program that you've shown should be well-formed. It compiles using clang and msvc. This is probably a GCC bug. [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90926) and/or [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67259) may be a report of the same bug.

You can work around the compiler bug by using a brace enclosed initialiser instead of a string literal:

```
std::vector<N> VN1 = {{
    {'a', '\0'},
    {'b', '\0'},
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the vector with a `const char` array instead of a `unit8_t`.
This should work:

```
std::vector<N> VN1 = {{'a','d'}};
```

This will initialize `b_1` only though.

Comment: Thanks this was the best I came up with seems I cannot just simply use "a" for a char a[2]; in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<N> VN1 = {{{'a','b'},{'c','d'}}};

std::cout << "output: " << VN1[0].b_1[0] << " " << VN1[0].b_1[1] << " " << VN1[0].b_2[0] << " " << VN1[0].b_2[1] << std::endl;
```

output: a b c d